# How to fork repository on stash?

Tags: rest, python-requests, bitbucket-server, git-fork

We can fork repository using this

```
 /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}
```

But I am not able to understand how to use it in python requests API ? 
It throws me 500 status code.

I used this:

```
requests.post("https://PROJECTURL/rest/api/1.0/projects/PRJ_KEY/repos/REPO_NAME",
  auth=("usename", "password"), verify=False)
```

Any idea how should I define this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide a POST payload even if it's empty JSON - eg: {}

Comment: requests.post("http://PROJECTURL/rest/api/1.0/projects/PRJ_KEY/repos/REPO_NAME", auth=("user", "password"), verify=False) this return me 200 status code, it  should return 201 correct?